# How to change the position of my JavaScript game on the home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Snake! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    <body>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Snake!</title>
        <div id="game">
            <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

I have created the javascript game above, however it always appears in the top left corner of the page. I have a css page to style the home page, what would i need to do in the html page and in the css page to move the game to a different position on the page?

**Update: the css page looks like this:**

```
body{
background-image:url(nokiaphone.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}

#game{
position:absolute;
left:1000px;
top:150px;
}
```

Comment: Please also include your relevant css in the question

Comment: Where do you want to move your game on the page ?

Comment: you should move the body tag outside of the head tag

Comment: you will need to show code both css and js specifically where you write to browser to be able to help you

Comment: define at least a width for your `#game div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "correct" HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Snake! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nokia">
        <div id="game">
            <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to move the game into the phone screen, maybe try this :

```
#game
{ 
    width: /*Here the width of your div in pixel ex : "450px;"*/ 
    margin-left: /*Here the distance in pixel from the left border of the image to the phone screen*/ 
    margin-right: /*Here the distance in pixel from the top border of the image to the phone screen*/         position relative;
}

#nokia
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(nokiaphone.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;

}
```

**In your javascript try :** (currently, you don't add your canvas in the "game" div but directly in the body, that's why your game do not move)

```
var div = document.getElementById('game');
div.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: So now, where do you want to move your game on the page ?

Comment: if you look here [link](http://users.aber.ac.uk/cew10/iwp-project/snake-game.html), the game shows up at the top left of the page, but i want it to be inside the nokia screen.

Comment: ok - maybe the first think to do is to mesure in pixel the distance between the top-left corner of the image and the top-left corner of the phone screen

Comment: If you update your code in the page you give me the link, I will be able to see modifications and give you a more precise solution :)

Comment: it still wont move from its original position

Comment: You have to modify your javascript : var div = document.getElementsByTagName('game')[0];
div.appendChild(canvas);

Comment: sorry, use document.getElementsById ... if it doesn't work again try to remove the [0]

Comment: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: document.getElementById (without "s" to element)

Comment: remove the [0] after the document.getElementById('game')

Comment: I see the game is in the center of the screen ! Great job ;)

Comment: i just have one more thing, if you have tried the game, you will see that the click to start button does nothing, how would i code this in my javascript?

Comment: Maybe try to call the drawGame() function at the end of your startPage() function (I think the drawGame function run the game). After you will see how to run the game by clicking on the scree.

Comment: i need to have a start page at the beginning with a start button as part of the assignment specification. this just starts the game without the start page

Comment: I see it's ok ! Maybe mark this question as solved and find a solution to start the game by clicking on the screen by googling ! ;) You will find for sure ! (maybe search for "click event canvas")

Comment: i have tried adding a pause function to the game, but for some reason it wont work. any advice?

Comment: when resizing the page, the background moves and the game stays in the same place. is there any way i can make the background stay where it is instead?

Answer (score 0):

You want it at the center of the page ?

The easiest solution if your `div#game` has fixed width height is :

```
#game {
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-250px; /*half of the height*/
    margin-left:-250px; /*half of the width*/
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/4yCwf/).

The full code'll be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Snake!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then in your `style.css` the previous css.

If you want more, here is a nice article about [centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

Comment: it seems to just stay in the same place when i do this

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is pretty messed up... with the `head` and `body` sections being confused. Try this example which will simply centre your game on the screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Snake!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    <style type="text/css">
        #game { width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```